# Parsing date and time using base R

Tags: r, date, datetime

```
x <- "15/06/2016 12:56:39" #where the format is dd/mm/Y and time
x <- as.POSIXct(strptime(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS"))
```

returns

```
"2016-06-15 12:56:39 CEST"
```

ignoring the format argument.

I tried passing ***strftime*** instead of *strptime*, but it throws an error about the string format being ambiguous.

How can I return a **timestamp** keeping the original `format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS"` using base R?

I know I could use *lubridate*, but in my current environment I cannot import new libraries.

Comment: does `as.POSIXct` have a format argument? I don't think so.

Comment: I believe, this question has been asked many times before on SO.

I believe, there is a misunderstanding. You need to distinguish between 

 (a) dates and date-times given as character strings, 
 (b) the internal representation of dates and date-times as class `Date` and `POSIXct` or the like, and
 (c) the default formatting when objects of class `Date` or `POSIXct` or the like are printed.

Comment: @Onyambu, Of course it has, see `?help("as.POSIXct")`. However, the timezone argument `tz` should be specified to avoid warnings.

Comment: is it because of the ellipsis?. Well i guess so.

Answer (score 1):

Just another format on top of that.

```
x <- "15/06/2016 12:56:39" #where the format is dd/mm/Y and time
format(strptime(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS"),"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS")
```

Comment: Thanks- but when I wrap it up in a as.POSIXct it still does not return the correct format.

Comment: @Abra Do you want a date object as the result, if that's the case what impact the format of date would play in your analysis?

Comment: I need to amend the format to ingest the data into a data visualization tool that is throwing a "date out of range error" because it interprets the dates using the locale settings, rather than ISO standard format.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
 x <- "2016-06-15 12:56:39" 
 x <- as.POSIXct(strftime(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned in my original post, stringftime throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this question has been asked many times before on SO.

I believe, there is a misunderstanding. You need to distinguish between

- dates and date-times given as character strings,
- the internal representation of dates and date-times as class `Date` and `POSIXct` or the like, and
- the default formatting when objects of class `Date` or `POSIXct` or the like are printed.

The benefit of the internal representation is that you can do date or date-time arithmetic, resp.,  and that it sorts correctly.

You need `format` in two places:

1. When coercing a character string to internal representation to tell where to look for the day, month, year, hours, minutes, and seconds information within the string and which characters to ignore.
2. When coercing an internal representation to a character string, for instance when printing, to tell where to put the day, month, year, hours, minutes, and seconds information in the desired output.

By default, the ISO standard format (`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`) is assumed in many places. The ISO format has the benefit that it is unambiguous and that it sorts well as character string.